# Changing a variable value in a dataframe through a function in R

Tags: r, function

**Dataframe**

```
df<-structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), V2 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L), V3 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

**Question**

To write a function that change the variable into:
A if the variable is 1
B if the variable is 2
C if the variable is 3

**What have I tried**

I've written a function but somehow it is unable to update the values outside of the function. If I run it direct, it works.

```
test_recode<-function(x){
        require("memisc")
        x<-cases("A"<-x==1,
                 "B"<-x==2,
                 "C"<-x==3)}
 test_recode(df$V1)
```

The function runs without error but the dataframe is still not altered.

However, it runs well without the function.

```
df$V1<-cases("A"<-df$V1==1,
             "B"<-df$V1==2,
             "C"<-df$V1==3)
```

**Further comments**

I did some research and found that it has to do with <- and <<- but when I altered x<- to x<<- it assigned values to x literally. How can I tell the function to assign the values to a variable I specify as a parameter?

Also, I need stick to the use of `memisc` `cases` function.

Comment: `switch` is the function you need: `df$V1 <- sapply(df$V1, switch, "A", "B", "C")` should do (concerning your function, you need to return something : `return(x)`)

Comment: and then, you will also need to assign the result, 
`df$V1<-test_recode(df$V1)`.

Comment: @mtoto: but I have already done the assignment in my function:

Comment: Thanks all. So apparently, you can't do the assignment (of a variable) within the function per se. You need to explicitly assign a dataframe to the function.

Comment: assignments made inside a function are made in the function environnement, not in the global environnement

Comment: *I need stick to the use of memisc cases function*: would that be a kind of homework? ;-). just put `return(x)` at the end of your function and do `df$V1 <- test_recode(df$V1)` and you'll get what you want

Comment: Thanks @Cath, I did the df$V1<-test_recode(df$V1), it worked. I was also hoping to find a way to assign a variable to the global environment but still take a parameter.

Comment: assigning a variable to the global environment inside a function is generally a bad idea

Comment: @Cath, thanks again. Will change my mindset.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach would be this:

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) chartr("123", "ABC", x))

#     V1  V2  V3 
#[1,] "A" "A" "B"
#[2,] "B" "C" "B"
#[3,] "B" "C" "A"
#[4,] "C" "A" "B"
#[5,] "B" "B" "C"
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this needs to be applied to every columns but apart from that very smart option :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility by using `LETTERS`,

```
sapply(df, function(i) LETTERS[i])
#     V1  V2  V3 
#[1,] "A" "A" "B"
#[2,] "B" "C" "B"
#[3,] "B" "C" "A"
#[4,] "C" "A" "B"
#[5,] "B" "B" "C"
```

Comment: I thought this, too. But you never know, if the row goes straight forward or if 4 could be "K" ;-).

Comment: @J_F Come on, 4 can never be 'K'... :) You are right though, It can not be very  generalized in theory